# Isomorphism of X to itself.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $(X, +, \bullet)$ and $(X,\tilde{+}, \tilde{\bullet})$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, and dim$(X, +, \bullet) =n$ (the set $X$ is the same in both spaces). Show that  $(X, +, \bullet)$ is isomorphic to $(X,\tilde{+}, \tilde{\bullet})$.

Comment: In this generality it's not true. Are there any connections between the operations?

Comment: Sorry for how I formulated the question, I didn't know if this had to be true, thanks! Could you give me counter example?, I find this really weird haha.

Comment: The key is that we have $|\Bbb R^2|=|\Bbb R|$, i.e. there's a bijection between $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R$, so e.g. we can impose a one dimensional vector space structure on $\Bbb R^2$ via this bijection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since two finite dimensional spaces (over the same field) are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension, it follows that:

$$(X, +, \bullet)\cong(X,\tilde{+}, \tilde{\bullet})$$

if and only if $$\dim (X,\tilde{+}, \tilde{\bullet}) = n$$

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the set is the same is a distraction. 
Choose a basis $(v_1, \dots,v_n)$ for $(X,+,\cdot)$. Choose a basis $w_1, \dots w_n$ for $(X, \tilde{+}, \tilde{\cdot})$.
Define $T:X \to X$ by $T(v_i)=w_i$ and extend the definition to $X$ linearly ($T(\alpha_1 \cdot v_i+ \alpha_2 \cdot v_j)=\alpha_1 \tilde{\cdot}T(v_i)\tilde{+}\alpha_2\tilde{\cdot}T(v_j)$). This map will be surjective as its onto the basis elements of $(X, \tilde{+}, \tilde{\cdot})$. By the rank nullity theorem it will be invective. 
(Check that this defines a linear map)

(This answer assumes that the dimensions are the same)